# What advantages can GWT give me over Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, gwt

I am comfortable with both Java and C#. Both with Eclipse and VisualStudio. So except I'll have to annoy people with installing Silverlight, is there something that should make me use GWT instead?

Comment: Without stating what sort of application you intend to write there can't really be an objective answer to this question.  You're only going to get emotive responses from GWT or Silverlight fanboys.  Very few have done serious work in both. You've already accepted the one answer you got and the question is only 10 hours old on a weekend.

Comment: its perfectly reasonable though

Comment: It "sounds" reasonable, I have no way to judge it since I know little about GWT.  It may sound reasonable to you because you know __all__ of your requirements.  However it can't be reasonable in the context of the above question alone because if it were then there would never been any reason to use anything that requires a plugin ever again.  Frankly I can't believe that that is yet true, perhaps in the future but not now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT is JavaScript, and JavaScript is a **standard**. If someone wanted to drastically change JavaScript, they'd have a hell of a time doing it.  Furthermore, GWT is **open-source**, so you can tell what they're doing and how they're doing it, if you have the time and inclination to investigate.

Silverlight is **closed-source** and **proprietary**, and as such is completely at the whim of one company, Microsoft. If you trust Microsoft not to drastically change the inner workings of Silverlight in a way that negatively effects your development, then this might not matter. But I personally don't.

Also, as you said, Silverlight requires a plug-in to use, which will be annoying to users not only the first time they have to download the plug-in, but also any time they have to *update* it to use new features, forever.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Any alternative for building RIA and not make user to install crap and use Java/C# ?

Comment: You could always write your browser-side code in regular ol' JavaScript, which would probably be easier if you use a framework like jQuery, Prototype, YUI, ExtJS, etc.

Comment: well jQuery does not use Java, does it? :)
Actually GWT will save me messing with JS (that's why I intend to use GWT or Silverlight)

Comment: Right, AFAIK GWT is the only RIA framework that doesn't require a plug-in and allows you to write the app in Java or C#